# Renderização de font no Mac deixa a font "Regular" parecida com "Bold"

Tags: html, css-font-face

estou com um problema de renderização de font no Mac. A font é de tamanho "Regular" e renderiza certinho no windows, porem, no Mac a mesma font fica parecida com "Bold".
O Windows é o Seven e o MAC é o Yosemite.

Estou usando esse código:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'open_sansregular';
src: url('font/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.eot');
src: url('font/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('font/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
     url('font/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('font/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('font/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.svg#open_sansregular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

(Tentei isso no body e no html, mas o problema ainda continua)

```
body {
font-family: 'open_sansregular';
color: #939393;
font-size: 14px;
-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */
-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
}
```

E as fontes ficam assim:

[image: WINDOWS, Chrome CORRETO]
[image: MAC, Chrome]
[image: MAC, Firefox]
[image: Zoom]

1 - Windows, Chrome (Correto)
2 - Mac, Chrome
3 - Mac, Firefox

Comment: @PedroHenrique no Opera e no Chrome ficou certinho, Obrigado.
Só não funcionou no firefox, tentei colocar:

`-moz-font-smoothing: antialiased;`


Mas não funcionou

Comment: Criei uma resposta atualizada, deve funcionar tanto para WebKit (Chrome, Safari) quanto para o Mozilla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que sei o Mac e Windows possuem algoritmos diferentes para calcular tamanho da fonte, se tratando de uma Web font a situação ainda fica mais complicada.

De qualquer forma você pode utilizar o seguinte código CSS

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
```

Isso deve deixar a aparência das fontes mais uniforme entre as plataformas.

Comment: Na mosca!RS  Agora esta tudo igual em ambos OS e Browsers, vlw